# How to fit lorentzian to lyman alpha cross section?

Tags: star

[image]

This is my data and purpose of this assignment is to fit a lorentzian to this data.
And.. i dont know how to do that....:(

First, there is sharply lowered region.
Couple of hours of googling isn't helpful..
Second, should I fit lorentzian for 2 times? 
There are two peaks.

Comment: Can you add  more information? Is this supposed to be an emission or absorption spectrum? What are all of the phenomenon discussed in the assignment? e.g. is there collisional or Doppler broadening? Peak on right is Lyman alpha at about 1215 Angstroms, and on the left is probably Lyman beta at about 1026 Angstroms. Also, you might consider plotting on a *linear scale* first as well, this spectrum has variations over seven orders of magnitude and there may be other effects important over that dynamic range.

Comment: I did with SED fluxes. I simply fitted the Lorentzian function with a fixed central wavelength (or constrained it within reasonable region). And, the SED has to be continuum subtracted fluxes. Would this work?